# Why does't work html input type: range control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Why does't work HTML input type: range control in asp.net? Have you any solutions for this problem?

In HTML code-

```
<input id="rangeCtrl" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="50" />
```

But is not work in ASP.NET

Comment: Can you give more detail on how it isn't working? Is it not being rendered on the page? Or rendering incorrectly? Are you not receiving the value on postback/submission? This question is difficult to answer without a description of the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: What browser are you using? Most should [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-range) it nowadays.

Comment: both firefox and chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **in ASP.net we need to use the HTML5 Doctype** then only it work properly

Answer (score 0):

This is by necessity a guess as you do not describe the problem you are experiencing, but it is noticeable that you have not provided a "name" attribute in your code -

From [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)-

> **name**
>
> The name of the control, which is submitted with the form data.

When the form is POSTed (submitted) to your server then the value will be sent keyed against this *name* and **not** the *id* as you might have assumed.

If the issue is that you cannot see the value selected by the user on the server, then you will need to change your code to-

```
<input id="rangeCtrl" name="rangeCtrl" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="50" />
```

Assuming you are using Web Forms (as opposed to Web Pages or MVC, you've not specified) then you can then access the data using the [Request.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object in your codebehind. In MVC the value will automatically be matched against a view model property of the same name.

Comment: Other Browsers also not working.. i think it have been some other problem in asp.net

Comment: @mansres Did you add the "name" attribute? **What** is it that isn't working? Is it not rendering correctly? The value not coming through on submit? The initial value not being populated on load? We need to know **what** isn't working before we can help you.

Comment: oh yes. i added attribute "name=rangeCtrl". but is not rendering in ".asp" like ".html" file. just it showing only one text box and inside the value is same as Value="50". here is no range scroll bar range set up. that i asking? did you understand?

Comment: What doctype are you using on your document? As it is a HTML5 control you need to use the HTML5 doctype. As the control doesn't exist in previous versions of HTML, it will not be rendered for documents in those modes - instead falling back to type "text" (the default) as you have seen. Incidentally, do your files have the .asp extension? That is **not** ASP.NET, but "Classic ASP" or "Active Server Pages".

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Introduction_to_HTML5 for details of the HTML 5 doctype.